# Vue objects got split on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I have a weird situation on one of my work projects using VueJS and a Python backend. It may no even related to Vue at all.

I'm using the `$data` property of a Vue component to store the params I'm sending the backend. One of those options is a list, so when on the frontend you do this...

```
this.$data.option
```

gets you get something like

```
["/dev/sda2 mounted at /boot", "udev mounted at /dev", "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root mounted at /"]
```

after that I simply do an ajax request to the server...

```
$.ajax({url: url, type: "POST", data: this.$data})
```

but what my server receives, instead of an expected string of comma separated values is this mess...

```
'options[0][label]': u'/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root mounted at /',
'options[0][value]': u'/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root mounted at /',
'options[2][label]': u'/dev/sda2 mounted at /boot',
'options[2][value]': u'/dev/sda2 mounted at /boot',
'options[4][label]': u'udev mounted at /dev',
'options[4][value]': u'udev mounted at /dev',
```

which is a split of the select field where I'm storing the options.

I tried dumping the object to a JSON and parsing it back but no luck

```
original_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$data));
```

Comment: Why are you sending `this.$data` to the server. Shouldn't it be `this.$data.options`?

Comment: this.$data is an object with several fields that I'm tracking of which I'm interested in the some of them, not all. I thought of taking them out into a pure javascript object, but is not an efficient solution, as is only a patch, and would involve doing in further in the future if I encounter this again.